# Using PIVOT in conjunction with a total summation in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data with a general structure:

```
DATE   CATEGORY   VALUE
------------------------------
A      X          X'
A      Y          X'
A      Z          Z'
```

I want to output a single row like:

```
DATE VALUE_X VALUE_Y VALUE_Z TOTAL
------------------------------------------
A    X'      Y'      Z'      X'+Y'+Z'
```

I can see that the way to approach this is with a PIVOT, but how would I do this whilst also calculating the total?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       max(value) filter (where category = 'X') as x,
       max(value) filter (where category = 'Y') as y,
       max(value) filter (where category = 'Z') as z,
       sum(value)
from t
group by date;
```

Note:  If you have values other than `'X'`, `'Y'`, and `'Z'`, then you might want either:

```
sum(value) filter (where category in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

or:

```
where where category in ('X', 'Y', 'Z'
```

I am also assuming that the last column is actually for the sum.  If you want a string aggregation, then the logic is:

```
       string_agg(value, '+' order by category)
```